# "I'm so sorry about it," what's wrong?

Tags: collocations

The following is a conversation from an English textbook (Summit 2A by Joan Saslow and Allen Ascher; Pearson Education, 2012) in which a person expresses regret about breaking his friend's camera.

> Tim, I hate to tell you this but I dropped the camera you lent me, and it can't be fixed.
>
> Oh, no. How did that happen?
>
> Well, I tripped, and it fell out of my bag. **I feel awful about it**.
>
> Are you sure it can't be fixed?
>
> Pretty sure. I took it to the camera shop, and they said to forget it. But I can replace it with a newer model.

Then the book suggests other ways to express regret as the following: *I'm so sorry; I feel awful (about it); I feel (just) terrible (about it)*.

The problem is it says *I'm so sorry* does not conclude with *about it*. Really? I'm pretty sure I've heard sorry about something or someone. What am getting wrong here?! Is it something about *so* before *sorry*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I'm so sorry *about it*** [the entire phrase] is not typically used to express regret about a particular thing that one has *done accidentally*, like dropping a camera or breaking a window with a baseball. Normally it is used to express regret about *an extended incident in which one was involved and took part*, such as an argument or a painful misunderstanding, and its aftermath.

> I'm so sorry about it (all).
>
> I'm so sorry about the whole thing.

Comment: Wow I couldn't possibly pull that in a billion years! Thank you very much. Now the whole thing makes sense.

Comment: It's also common to say *(I'm) (so) sorry about that.* Where *that* can refer to a wide range of things. In speech that is not formal, the *about* is often shortened to *'bout.* That might explain why you think you've heard *sorry about (something).*